# GITLAB - Fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, docker, gitlab, supervisord

**First of all, thank you so much** for your attention on this important issue that I'm dealing right now...
See the image below then keep reading the text:

So, I believe ***the issue itself is not even with the front/back end codes***(as you can see in the image) but just to you know this project is using VueJS/JavaScript, Sass, and Laravel/PHP, and ***I use sourcetree for the git part but this project also uses Docker***, and I don't know and I never used Docker in my life...

In this project, any changes that is made mainly in the front end code, I need to compile(***npm run production***), and after it is already in Gitlab, I also ***need to reset and start again the supervisord on the server*** for the back end code(Laravel).

Here in the company, I'm using sourcetree where I can click on stage all button, commit button and push button to GitLab. Doing this, I can see a small icon aside of the project name showing that it is commiting and after one or three minutes I see another icon: a green one or a red one with an error icon saying that the deploy failed...

***If you see the image that I sent***, It is saying about the repository, but I am in the right repository(I almost don't work in this project and the last time it worked fine).

Do you guys have any idea how to fix it?
I will save my job here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error message: `Permission denied (publickey,...)`, the public/private ssh keys being used to authenticate are not correct. Can you ssh into the devhost? I find the `ssh -T user@hostname` command helpful for troubleshooting in these cases.

Also, check out this [guide on troubleshooting ssh issues](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/troubleshooting-ssh/).

Comment: Hello Richard. Thank you for your answer. Yesterday looking about it, I have more details:

Comment: Yes, I agree with that. Add the `-v` flag to your ssh command, edit the output to remove any personal details, and update your post with the output.

Comment: It didn't work Richard... It is showing the same error. I didn't find the Gitlab runner service to see the user inside and edit it for root... I'm almost now putting the code manually inside the server and restart the supervisord to see the results in the back end code(laravel). :(

Comment: In your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, change the line to include the verbose option: `ssh -v root@$DEV_SERVER`. Commit and push to trigger the pipeline. What is the output?

Comment: Hi Richard, good morning. You are helping me a lot and thank you for that. So, I changed the code there inside the yml file(I put the "-v" in front of ssh), then I used npm run production to compile the code and finally used again the sourcetree to push and wait for the deploy... I have two stages inside yml file: test and deploy. The test always works fine. Now the deploy is showing this but it is still showing permission denied too:

Comment: I get an HTTP 403 Forbidden error code when visiting that link.

Comment: Hi Richard. It was showing the same error and unfortunatily, I needed to change manually because of the time here. But thank you so much for your help Richard.